# webpacker stops working in react-on-rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-on-rails

I'm unable to push my app to heroku because I get the following error when I run

```
 ruby ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

with the following version **[(ruby-2.6.0)]**

> ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/hello-world-bundle.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../bundles/HelloWorld/components/HelloWorld' in '/Users/.../app/javascript/packs'

I haven't touched the files, after the initialization of the project which generated them.

Here is my **packages.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-on-rails": "11.2.2",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}
```

And here is my webpacker configuration

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take 

effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

I have tried every single thread on stack overflow and github issues. Please help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've sunk way too much time into it but Heroku's errors aren't very helpful and everything builds locally without trouble.